# Train tesseract 3.04

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I would like to train **tesseract v3.04**.

I currently have generated box files from some images, and I am not sure where to go next.

The images are **"png"** format.

This is to be used with **pytesseract**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [**jTessBoxEditor.**](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html)

**jTessBoxEditor** is a box editor and trainer for Tesseract OCR (Both 2.0x and 3.0x formats) and provides full automation of Tesseract training.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Out of interest, how would I go about training Tesseract 4?

Comment: @user98651 You will have to do it using the command line. The full guide can be found [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00).

Additionally, there is an online tool [Train Your Tesseract](http://trainyourtesseract.com/) which can create a traineddate file using a TTF or OTF font file. But I'm not sure whether it works for Tess4.